# How to plus values of multi arrays

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

**Here is my code in blade Laravel:**

```
@php
$serialize = array_map("serialize", $arrayplus);
$uniqueSerialize = array_unique($serialize);
$amountplus = array_map("unserialize", $uniqueSerialize);
dd($amountplus);
@endphp
```

When I use array_sum() function its return 0 I am trying to plus values of multi arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
@php
$serialize = array_map("serialize", $arrayplus);
$uniqueSerialize = array_unique($serialize);
$amountplus = array_map("unserialize", $uniqueSerialize);
    $sum = 0;
    @if(!empty($amountplus))
        @foreach($amountplus as $amount)
            $sum += $amount['amount'];
        @endforeach
    @endif
    echo $sum;

@endphp
```

and if you want to use array_sum then you need to do it as below.

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($amountplus) { 
    return $amountplus['amount']; 
}, $amountplus));
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Glad to help you. select the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code, for array_walk_recursive function

```
@php
$array = array(
    array('amount'=>1689.3),
    array('amount'=>1494),
);

$total = 0;
array_walk_recursive($array,function($array_key) use (&$total){
    $total += $array_key;
});
print_r($total);
@endphp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_sum()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) with [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
echo array_sum(array_column($array,'amount'));
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LD5mf)**